# Stop Mathematica from turning negative powers into reciprocals of positive powers

Tags: output-formatting

Is there a way to stop Mathematica from turning every negative power $z^{-n}$ into $1/z^n$ in TraditionalForm?  I'd like to get this:

[image: Negative power]

but `1/(1 - p z^-1) // TraditionalForm` gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `1/(1 - p z^HoldForm[-1])` ?

Comment: That never occurred to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that these forms are interchangeable in *Mathematica*, by which I mean that there is both interconversion and that display does not match the internal form.

`Power[x, -1]` is *displayed* as `1/x`, and `1/x` is *read as* `Times[1, Power[x, -1]]`.

```
a/b

% // FullForm
```

> ```
> a/b
>
> Times[a, Power[b, -1]]
> ```

So you cannot automatically have `1/(1 - p z^-1)` displayed as [image: ]] without rules to distinguish the main reciprocal from the lower one.

You *can* prevent formatting by making `-1` a non-number using [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) or [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) as LouisB recommended in a comment:

```
1/(1 - p z^Defer[-1]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

I am not sure if this kind of manual intervention is what you are seeking.

For the particular case this formatting rule on [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html) gets the job done but it may affect, or fail to affect, the display of other expressions in a way you do not want.

```
MakeBoxes[a_*x_^-1, TraditionalForm] := 
  ToBoxes[a*Superscript[x, -1], TraditionalForm]
```

Now:

```
1/(1 - p z^-1) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: If I change the pattern to `a_*z^-n_` the `MakeBoxes` function does just what I need.  Thank you.

Comment: @Rodney In that case I'm glad I could help. :-)